# Avoid state transition occuring twice in $state.go or uisref

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-router-extras

Using UIRouter, trying to navigate from a child state [A.childa with url "localhost:90/A/childa/212"]to a different state [B], but the transition is occuring twice [like on click of a button the url changes from "localhost:90/A/childa/212" to localhost:90/A/childa and then on clicking again it changes to localhost:90/B". I need the localhost:90/A/childa/212 to directly change to localhost:90/B using uisref or $state.go. How can we do it?

```
$stateProvider.state('A', {
                url: '/A', 
                templateUrl: 'assets/templates/A.html',
                controller: 'ACtrl'
            }).state('A.childa', {
                    url: '/childa/:id',                        
                    templateUrl: 'assets/templates/childa.html',
                    controller: 'ChildaCtrl'
            });
$stateProvider.state('B', {
                    url: '/B', 
                    templateUrl: 'assets/templates/B.html',
                    controller: 'BCtrl'
                });
```

Comment: Not sure it is realted and mistake in your code, but you are reffering to the parent as A not parentA

Comment: @eesdil thats a typo mistake. Any solution for this issue?